TypeError: Cannot open database because the directory does not exist in Next.js app deployed on Vercel using Prisma with SQLite
I am working on a Next.js project deployed on Vercel, using Prisma with SQLite databases. The project runs fine locally, but on Vercel, I keep encountering the following error:
TypeError: Cannot open database because the directory does not exist at new Database (/var/task/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:65:9)

It seems that Vercel's serverless environment is unable to open the database file because the directory doesn’t exist. Here's how my database URLs are defined in the environment variables:
DATABASE_URL="file:./welisara.db"
USER_DATABASE_URL="file:./userswelisara.db"

Steps I've Tried:
Locally, everything works perfectly. The SQLite databases are created and accessed correctly.
On Vercel, I believe this issue might be related to the fact that the Vercel environment is read-only,
How to fix this issue

SQLite is incompatible with serverless environments (in your case Vercel) because it lacks a persistent filesystem for data storage and creates isolated function instances that can't share a central database.
Reference - Is SQLite supported in Vercel?
Consider cloud databases like Postgres Neon, Turso, or Vercel Postgres.
